# Trying to disable dragging of a JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, applet, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have been looking around for awhile and can't find a method for disabling dragging a JIntenal Frame.  Any help would be appreciaed -TYIA, Roland

Please keep in mind this is an applet,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class inigui2 extends Applet {

    public void init() {

        final JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        desktop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        this.add(desktop);

        JInternalFrame fr = new JInternalFrame("internal", false, false, false, false);
        fr.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
        desktop.add(fr);
        fr.setVisible(true);

        JInternalFrame fr2 = new JInternalFrame("internal2", true, true, true, true);
        fr2.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);
        desktop.add(fr2);
        fr2.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: You will find [this tutorial](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/9214-disable-drag-mode-jinternal-frame.html) useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could remove all `MouseMotionListeners` for `JInternalFrames`:

```
JInternalFrame[] frames = desktop.getAllFrames();
for (JInternalFrame frame: frames) {
   BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI) frame.getUI();
   Component northPane = ui.getNorthPane();
   MouseMotionListener[] motionListeners = (MouseMotionListener[]) northPane.getListeners(MouseMotionListener.class);

   for (MouseMotionListener listener: motionListeners)
      northPane.removeMouseMotionListener(listener);
   }
}
```

Comment: thats great!  I need to only freese one frame but TYVM - Roland