# How to add picture out of JFrame, attached to border

Tags: java, jframe

Hi I Would like add to my JFrame border some image.
Is this Possible to attach picture to borders for JFrame and create it as 1 object ?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question for us.

Comment: I meant that whole this frame and phone hanger would be treated as 1 object. It is like crating better looking  Frame. For example in the games, asume that Heal Mark is a circle and the frame of it is a circle. I would like add to this frame something like this http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs51/f/2009/340/7/b/HP_Bars_by_Project_Garnia.png   And I would like to do the same with this.Is it more clearly right now ?

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html ?

Comment: Yep but it isn't it. His is more about shape of frame with some graphics on it

Comment: The single way is to set your `JFrame` undecorated and draw the frame border and top right buttons by out own. PS: The real `JFrame` size would be bigger than is seems. Outside background should be `opaque`. Then, use `JLayeredPane` to draw your outside content.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Hi, any chance my answer can claim the bounty?

Comment: @NickG: You'll have to wait and see. The bounty doesn't end til tomorrow.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thanks! I wasn't sure how it worked.

Comment: @NickG: There ya go, your bonus has been granted. Your answer so far has garnered 155 rep points for you, congrats and enjoy in peace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to add the image directly to the border of a JFrame (suggestions welcome). I decided to solve this issue by using a transparent content pane, and using an inner frame to "appear" like the outer frame.

The code is pretty simple, however, let me know if you'd like an explanation of how the code works.

**Here's the minimum code you'll need to get up and running.**

You'll need to provide your own `transparent-phone.png` image, in the root of the classpath (i.e. next to your PhoneWindow.java file, in the root package).

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PhoneWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PhoneWindow();
    }

    public PhoneWindow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    // create the  inner frame
                    final JInternalFrame frame2 = new JInternalFrame("My Telephone");
                    frame2.setClosable(true);
                    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                    // add elements to the outer frame
                    frame.setUndecorated(true);
                    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                    JPanel pane = new TranslucentPane();
                    frame.setContentPane(pane);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    // add inner frame and phone picture
                    frame.add(frame2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/transparent-phone.png")))), BorderLayout.EAST);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
                    frame.pack();
                    // show
                    frame2.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public class TranslucentPane extends JPanel {

        public TranslucentPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0f));
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

    }

}
```

**Here's the full Java class (including close and draggable behaviour)**

https://gist.github.com/nickgrealy/16901a6428cb79d4f179

**And here's a screenshot of the final product**

N.B. the transparent sections inside/outside the phone.

[image: The final result with transparency.]

**References:**

- [How to make a transparent JFrame but keep everything else the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927980/how-to-make-a-transparent-jframe-but-keep-everything-else-the-same)
- [Trying to disable dragging of a JInternalFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783753/trying-to-disable-dragging-of-a-jinternalframe)